# Regular expression for excluding specific name string for the name field?

Tags: javascript, regex

I m trying to create a regular expression that goes with all the name but excluding name like 'test','dummy','percentage','crap'

but if i m typing 'est' ,'ummy' it is not taking.

As a group it should not accept, but currently it is excluding a single character.

I tried this :
    `[^@test]`

please ask for any confirmation

Comment: Maybe regular expressions aren't the best approach?

Comment: actually my form getting loaded by the backend json, so i have to bind the regex from their

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *have* to use a regular expression, use negative lookahead from the beginning of the string:

```js
const validate = str => /^(?!(test|dummy|percentage|crap)$)/.test(str);
console.log(validate('test'));
console.log(validate('est'));
console.log(validate('testt'));
console.log(validate('foo'));
console.log(validate('dumm'));
console.log(validate('dummy'));
```

If you don't, use `includes`:

```
const validate = str => !['test', 'dummy', 'percentage', 'crap'].includes(str);
```

Comment: Note that the `includes` method [will fail on IE < 14](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes), among other browsers. If you can use newer features, then you should use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead, as it’s better supported and designed for this use case. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 1):

`[^@test]` matches a single character that is not one of `@`, `t`, `e`, and `s`.

Like Cerbrus said, regexes aren’t the right tool for this.

You can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) if you can count on IE 11+:

```
const forbidden = new Set([
  "test",
  "dummy",
  "crap"
]);

function shouldAllow(word) {
  return forbidden.has(word);
}
```

---

Otherwise, you can use an array and `indexOf` instead:

```
const forbidden = [
  "test",
  "dummy",
  "crap"
];

function shouldAllow(word) {
  return forbidden.indexOf(word) == -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `regex` why don't you harness the power of JavaScript's [`array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to write a one liner Arrow function (`=>`) like this:

```js
excludeList = ['test','dummy','percentage','crap']

isInExcludeList = (testName) => excludeList.includes(testName)

console.log(isInExcludeList('dummy')) //true
console.log(isInExcludeList('dum'))   //false
```

Advantage: It'll make your code easy to maintain.